# how to convert and send date from model to controller

Tags: php, laravel

I was looking for a method to convert the jalali date to Georgian using Carbon and store it in the corresponding DB table. I found the following method on youtube, in which after converting the date in the model, it sends it to the controller:

```
public function  setTaskDateAttribute($TaskDate)
{
    $this->attributes['TaskDate'] = CalendarUtils::convertNumbers($TaskDate, true);
    $this->attributes['TaskDate'] = CalendarUtils::createCarbonFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->attributes['TaskDate'])->format('Y-m-d');
    dd($this->TaskDate);

}
```

in controller:

```
public function store(taskRequestStore $request,TaskService $service)
{
    dd($request->TaskDate);
   $attributes = $request->all(['office_id','TaskDate','Type','Priority_id']);
   $office = $service->create($attributes);
}
```

modified: The dd function inside the setTaskDateAttribute function returns the georgian date value, but in the store function in the controller dd($request->TaskDate); The initial value of Jalali date is still returned. I want georgian date to be stored in table.
Please help me to fix the problem

Comment: You should use $this->attributes instead of $this.Attribute.

Comment: I did what you said and I don't get an error, but if I use dd($request->TaskDate) in the controller, the initial value is still TaskDate, and the transformation I implemented in the model did not affect TaskDate. Also if dd($this->TaskDate); add in the model will display the value of the date in georgian!